# importing postgres database dump to local app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a db dump in pg from heroku. I want to use that db locally as well.

How can we have that database dump imported locally  using `pgadmin`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a database in `PG` and make the dump import to that database

```
$ pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U [username] -d [database name] latest.dump
```

For references you can view this blog:
https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2016/01/22/heroku-postgresql-dump-production-staging-database-to-localhost/

Comment: how do I specify the path of `latest.dump`. It is under my home directory

Comment: You can do ~/ as it defines our home directory

Comment: **could not open input file "/home/suraj/database.dump": No such file or directory**
 this is what I am getting with `pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U [sur] -d [development_db] ~/database.dump`

Comment: I ve not tried with using paths. Always dumped the database in the project directory itself. But let me try again

Comment: Are you still having problem?

Comment: yes, I am unable to load this dump locally but I think some other issue

Answer (score 0):

Use this command for restoring

'pg_restore -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres_user_name -d database_name -v “LATEST_DUMP_PATH”'

Answer (score 0):

I use the following, simple and to the point:

```
pg_restore -d database_name -c ~/database.dump
```